# How to use python3.5 with virtualenv, even if the system globally has 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have python 2.7 installed globally on my machine - Mac OSX. I tried have installed python 3.5 just by downloading the file but haven't changed PYTHONPATH / any PATH variables as I was not sure what to do. I am now running a virtualenv in which python 3.5 is installed. But when I try to run any modules I wrote, it says "ImportError: No module named XYZ". It is running fine when I am out of the virtualenv.

Is this because of PYTHONPATH ? if so, what changes need to be made. Also can anyone point me to a tutorial on how to install python 3.5 and make it running fully functional?

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv). I believe that is what you are looking for. Also please search a bit more next time when asking :) Have a great day!

Comment: I saw that post long back and created a virtualenv with python3.5. My problem is with "ImportError: No module named XYZ" when working on virtualenv with 3.5, but it runs fine on python2.7.

Comment: Can you run python 3.5 in your virtualenv? Also mind changing the title to something like "ImportError: No module named XYZ while using python3.5 in virtualenv"